# SQL select parent and child from different tables

Tags: sql-server, parent-child

I have 2 tables: Customer and SubAccount.
`Customer(customerId, customerName, address, city, state)`
`SubAccount(subAccountID, subAccountName, customerID, subAddress, subCity, subState)`
I want to select the parent customer AND each of their sub accounts like so:

```
+------------+---------------+
| Customer   |  SubAccount   |
+------------+---------------+
| Customer1  |  null         |
| Customer1  |  SubAccount1  |
| Customer1  |  SubAccount2  |
| Customer2  |  null         |
| Customer2  |  SubAccount1  |
| Customer3  |  null         |
| Customer3  |  SubAccount1  |
+------------+---------------+
```

However, doing a simple

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName, SubAccount.subAccountName
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN SubAccount ON SubAccount.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerID
```

doesn't work. it only shows

```
+------------+---------------+
| Customer   |  SubAccount   |
+------------+---------------+
| Customer1  |  SubAccount1  |
| Customer1  |  SubAccount2  |
| Customer2  |  SubAccount1  |
| Customer3  |  SubAccount1  |
+------------+---------------+
```

What is the correct way to do the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION ALL your existing query with a simple query selecting CustomerName and NULL (AS SubAccount) from the Customers table (no join).

Comment: Nice simple solution

Comment: That works except if a customer does not have a subaccount, then the customerName shows up twice

Comment: doing a `UNION` and not a `UNION ALL` works like I want.

Comment: Or doing a UNION ALL with an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN.